# How do I convert numbers with e to digits only?

Tags: python, math, numbers, long-integer

I want to convert numbers like 1.28e+21 to a long digits only number but the following code doesn't make a difference.
`n = 1.28e+21 b = 1.28*10**21 print(b)`

b still has an e.

How do I get rid of e?

Comment: What form does your input take? Are you starting with the string `"1.28e+21"` or a Python `float` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These numbers in exponential format are from type `float` in python.You can use `int` to convert it to an integer.

```py
>>> n = int(1.28e+21)
>>> n
1280000000000000000000
```

You can also use `decimal` module like this:

```py
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal(1.28e+21)
Decimal('1280000000000000000000')
>>>
```